# set value in 2d arraylist Java

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

i have 2d ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<List<Integer>> group;
group.add(Arrays.asList(i1, i2, i3));
group.add(Arrays.asList(i4, i5, i6));
group.add(Arrays.asList(i7, i8, i9));
```

how to set value on for example i5?

i should use:

```
group.set(index, value);
```

but how get correct index i5?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should get the second `List` first and then set the element in this list.

So it should be :

```
group.get(1).set(1, value); 
       ^      ^
       |      |
       |     set the second value of this list to value
       |
get the second List
```

[**Demo here.**](http://ideone.com/bHTaKN)

If you want to write a method to set the value of the element you want you can do (you may check for indexes) :

```
public static void setValue(List<List<Integer>> list, int row, int column, int value){
     list.get(row).set(column, value);
}
```